# How to put elements in an array with for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I am trying to insert elements into an array called "count" with a for loop. But the elements inside the array remain as 0 no matter what. I want it to print the desired output so that the numbers increments and does not remain 0 for all the indexes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int count[1] = {0}; //initialize array with 0

    printf("\nEnter an int for n: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         printf("%d \n", count[i]);
     }
```

**My current output -**
Enter an int for n: 6

0

0

0

0

0

0

**Desired Output** -

0

1

2

3

4

5

Comment: The array is declared to hold only 1 element. Assigning to anything beyond `count[0]` causes undefined behavior. C arrays don't expand automatically.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C arrays can't grow beyond their declared size. You need to declare the array with the intended size, not `count[1]`. You can do this by putting the declaration after you read `n`; this is called a *variable-length array*.

Then you can use a loop to initialize all the elements with consecutive numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    printf("\nEnter an int for n: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    int count[n];
    // initialize array with consecutive numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", count[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code leads to an error, It says for the int count[n] = {0} line that "expression must have a constant value".

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you can't initialize a VLA, it has to be done in the loop.